# I can't boot the ISO file

Tags: boot, iso

I have tried to boot the ISO file in my computer but I couldn't. I'm using Windows 7 and I save the file in my flash drive. When I tried to boot the flash drive appear the following message: Remove any CD or Media. Press any key for restart - or something similar.

What can I do in order to initiate the ISO file ?

Comment: Your USB stick isn't bootable. I think you just copied .iso file into flash USB? right? use one of bootable creator software and make it as bootable flash and try to boot. personally I'm using [UUI program](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Comment: Yes, I thought that the ISO file provided from the official site of ubuntu is bootable. Anyway.. I did exactly what kyidake told me and now is working.
Thank you for your help also !

Answer (score 4):

You must create a bootable usb stick with imagen.iso.

For this task, you can use this program:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6.exe

This program, as stated on their site:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Demand:

```
USB stick Fat16/Fat32/NTFS formatted
Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6.exe
Windows XP/Vista/7/8 
PC with a BIOS that can boot from USB
Linux image.iso
```

The procedure is as follows:

Download and install a Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6.exe

Run it

Select Ubuntu from the dropdown list.

Press Browse and open the downloaded image.iso

Choose the USB stick and press Create

Comment: Thank you dude! I did exactly what you said and yesterday I tried for a while the live ubuntu without installation. Today I'm thinking to install it.